# Rules with global flags in VBO

Tags: 7, rules

I am using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and [Flags](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) modules. I applied a patch to get  the uid is associated with the global flag (otherwise uid is set to 0).  Now how do I get Rules to work with global flags? I am trying to create a rules component, that I can use from Views Bulk Operations, so that if a node in the View was flagged by the current user, only then must the Rule execute on that node via VBO operation. As of now the Rule executes for all nodes. I want to put in some condition or some thing in the Rule, so it checks if the node's global flag's uid is the same as current user and only if so, executes action on that node. Is this possible?

```
{ "rules_unlock_pages" : {
    "LABEL" : "Unlock pages",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule set",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "editorial workflow" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "flag" ],
    "ACCESS_EXPOSED" : "1",
    "USES VARIABLES" : {
      "locked_node" : { "label" : "Locked Page", "type" : "node" },
      "flag" : { "label" : "flag", "type" : "flag" },
      "flagging" : { "label" : "flagging", "type" : "flagging" }
    },
    "RULES" : [
      { "RULE" : {
          "IF" : [
            { "node_is_of_type" : { "node" : [ "locked-node" ], "type" : { "value" : { "page" : "page" } } } },
            { "flag_flagged_node" : {
                "flag" : "edit_in_progress",
                "node" : [ "locked-node" ],
                "flagging_user" : [ "site:current-user" ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "DO" : [
            { "flag_unflagnode" : {
                "flag" : "edit_in_progress",
                "node" : [ "locked-node" ],
                "flagging_user" : [ "site:current-user" ],
                "permission_check" : "0"
              }
            }
          ],
          "LABEL" : "Unlock pages locked for edit by current user"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

https://www.drupal.org/node/2087797 is the patch I applied to record global flag's uid.